# trigger onclick over blocked iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `iframe` that is blocked, and I can't access inside of it to change through javascript.

I have the iframe inside div which has an `onclick` event, but it doesn't work, because of the iframe.  It only works only when clicked on border.

Now can anyone suggest me some solution here, because I can't come up with any idea for this.

Comment: You have it but we don't have it.Please edit with codes

Comment: I can't show the iframe's website, but I can show what I get when I trying to access iframe's content: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "mydomain.com"; from accessing a frame with origin "iframedomain.com";. Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Answer (score 0):

Add the click event to the iframe's `contentDocument`, so it acts as part of the div's click event:

```
iframe = document.getElementById("yourIframe");
iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    iframe.src = "newURLForYourIframe";
});
```

It will change the iframe's src, which I think (I didn't really understand what you said when you said 'change through javascript') is what you want.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqTnz/15/)

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, because when I trying to access iframe's content I get this: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://mydomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://iframedomain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: @Simon Wrap it around `try` and `catch` and tell us what it returns.